# Is there a platform where std::time_t is not represented as unix time?

Tags: c++, time, implementation

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t :

> **time_t**
>
> Alias of a fundamental arithmetic type capable of representing times, as those returned by function time.
>
> For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., a unix timestamp). **Although libraries may implement this type using alternative time representations.**
>
> **Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types.**

Does someone know an example of such implementation where std::time_t is not represented as unix time?

Comment: Side note: avoid cplusplus.com. It contains lots of misleading and wrong information.

Comment: Since we cannot look into the future there is no way to give you an exhaustive answer.

Comment: @rightfold You could have pointed an alternative, e.g. cppreference.com ([`std::time_t` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)).

Comment: @rightfold - the quoted commentary is exactly right.

Comment: @PeteBecker hence “Side note”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per §17.6.4.3.4/1:

> For each type T from the Standard C library,<sup>184</sup> the types ::T and std::T are reserved to the implementation and, when defined, ::T shall be identical to std::T.
>
> <sup>184</sup> ... time_t ...

So, both `time_t` and `std::time_t` are implementation defined types. The hint is somehow correct.

POSIX compatible systems try to implement it as unix time, but POSIX is not based on C++ standard and vice-versa. Maybe a C++ compiler in a specific embedded system will be created at future that has a different `time_t`...